# How to pin YouTube comments with Python automatically

Tags: python, youtube

I need to find a way to **pin comments** in YouTube automatically. I have checked YouTube API v3 documentation but it does not have this feature. Is there any idea?

Comment: The single solution AFAIK is reverse-engineering YouTube UI when pinning a comment with your web-browser Network developer tool tab.

Answer (score 0):

To initialize the automatic mechanism, you first need to open your web-browser Web Developer Tools `Network` tab, then pin an ad hoc comment, you should notice a XHR request to `perform_comment_action` endpoint. Right-click this request and copy it as cURL. Notice the last field `actions` in the JSON encoded `--data-raw` argument. Decode this base64 encoded field and modify the first plaintext argument `Ug...Ag` to the comment id you want to pin and re-encode the field in base64 and then execute the cURL request and that's it!

Note that there is no need to modify any other parameter for pinning a comment on another video than the ad hoc comment is posted on.