# How to insert a comment pinned to the top

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the youtube API to insert videos and in the end insert a comment. It's all working, though, I'd like to leave the pinned comment at the top. How could I do this?

My current code is like this:

```
$commentSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_CommentSnippet();
$commentSnippet->setTextOriginal('My Commment');
$topLevelComment = new Google_Service_YouTube_Comment();
$topLevelComment->setSnippet($commentSnippet);
$commentThreadSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_CommentThreadSnippet();
$commentThreadSnippet->setTopLevelComment($topLevelComment);
$commentThread = new Google_Service_YouTube_CommentThread();
$commentThread->setSnippet($commentThreadSnippet);
$commentThreadSnippet->setVideoId($videoId);
$videoCommentInsertResponse = $youtube->commentThreads->insert('snippet', $commentThread);
```

Comment: Duplicated with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73444163/7123660).

Comment: Hello.. But she doesn't answer the question