# Is there a programmatic way to "pin" a top-level comment via python?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, comments

I am looking for any possible solution to associate a top-level comment as a "pinned" comment.
(The behavior once you've pinned a comment for a YouTube video.)

I have scoured the internet looking for a better answer than "it is not supported" when it seems there could be curl tricks that I might pass into a python subprocess. Ideally this would be a flag while generating a top-level comment. and if it is and I missed it, please direct me to the docs.

Looking for a novel solution if none is officially supported.

Thank you

Current block of code that generates a top-level comment
But I am unsure of any flags to mark this as a "pinned" comment

```py
        self.youtube.commentThreads().insert(
            part="snippet",
            body={
                "snippet": {
                    "channelId": self.channelId,
                    "videoId": vidId,
                    "topLevelComment": {
                        "snippet": {
                            "textOriginal": self.textOriginal,
                        }
                    },
                }
            },
        ).execute()
```

I have also read this post
[How to pin Youtube comments with python automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73444163/how-to-pin-youtube-comments-with-python-automatically)

I am not sure if I need to build a template curl command, fill the necessary fields and then convert it to base64 before running the command?